# C++ how to shrink an image using a pointer array?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, pixel

I'm writing a c++ program that manipulates images, and this is the function to shrink it.  There is a 'pixel' pointer array and a class that has the image colors defined.  I cannot use any other library besides the ones included in Visual Studio for this image program.  I'm having an issue with this function, I need to traverse the pixels in the image and split it into blocks; the user will enter the block width/height.  After the blocks are created, the average RGB values need to be taken from each block (that average will become a single new pixel), and with all of them arranged it will 'shrink' the image.  So far it seems the blocks are created because the image becomes smaller, but my image turns completely gray. The totals for the RGB pixels are adding correctly, but something must be off in the rest of the code and I haven't been able to pinpoint it. Here is my code:

```
//creates a block of average colors based on range of pixels given
pixel CreateBlock(int start, int stop, pixel** currpix, int blockHeight, int blockWidth)
{
    pixel** block;          //Problem? might have to be a single pointer pixel* block[];
    block = new pixel*[blockHeight];

    for (int i = 0; i < blockHeight; i++)
        block[i] = new pixel[blockWidth];

    pixel newPix;

    float totred = 0, totblue = 0, totgreen = 0;
    int redav = 0.0, blueav = 0.0, greenav = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < blockHeight; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < blockWidth; j++)
        {
            totred = totred + block[i][j].red;
            totblue = totblue + block[i][j].blue;
            totgreen = totgreen + block[i][j].green;
        }
    }

    redav = totred / (blockHeight*blockWidth);
    blueav = totblue / (blockHeight* blockWidth);
    greenav = totgreen / (blockHeight*blockWidth);

    newPix.red = redav;
    newPix.blue = blueav;
    newPix.green = greenav;

    return newPix;
}

//make a new image that is a smaller resampling of the bigger image
void averageRegions(int blockWidth, int blockHeight)
{
    int height = displayed->getHeight(), width = displayed->getWidth();
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    pixel** currpix = displayed->getPixels();           //PROBLEM
    image* shrunk = displayed;
    //shrunk->getPixels();
    shrunk->createNewImage(width / blockWidth, height / blockHeight);
    while (i < height)
    {
        while (j < width)
        {
            int start = i, stop = i + 10;
            shrunk->getPixels()[i][j] = CreateBlock(start, stop, currpix, blockHeight, blockWidth);
            j = j + blockWidth;
        }
        i = i + blockHeight;
    }

    return;
}
```

Here is the image class:

```
class image {
    public:
        image();            //the image constructor (initializes everything)
        image(string filename);  //a image constructor that directly loads an image from disk
        ~image();           //the image destructor  (deletes the dynamically created pixel array)

        void createNewImage(int width, int height); //this function deletes any current image data and creates a new blank image
                                                //with the specified width/height and allocates the needed number of pixels
                                                //dynamically.
        bool loadImage(string filename);        //load an image from the specified file path.  Return true if it works, false if it is not a valid image.
                                            //Note that we only accept images of the RGB 8bit colorspace!
        void saveImage(string filename);       //Save an image to the specified path
        pixel** getPixels();                    //return the 2-dimensional pixels array
        int getWidth();                     //return the width of the image
        int getHeight();                    //return the height of the image

        void viewImage(CImage* myImage);  //This function is called by the windows GUI.  It returns the image in format the GUI understands.


    private:
        void pixelsToCImage(CImage* myImage);  //this function is called internally by the image class.
                                            //it converts our pixel struct array to a standard BGR uchar array with word spacing.
                                            //(Don't worry about what this does)
        pixel** pixels;             // pixel data array for image 
        int width, height;      // stores the image dimensions 
};
```

Here is the pixel class:

```
class pixel
{
public:
    unsigned char red;      //the red component
    unsigned char green;    //the green component
    unsigned char blue;     //the blue component
};
```

Comment: We know far too little about `displayed`, especially the called methods and what they do. Also, what about the other names used?

Comment: Unless my eyes are deceiving me, you have a huge memory leak in your `CreateBlock` function.

Comment: What are you doing with `block` in `CreateBlock`?  You allocate memory, then do nothing with it.  Either way, `CreateBlock` seems to be a misleading name, if you're only creating one pixel out of that block, as the return value would imply.  As for the rest of it, what exactly does the `displayed` class contain?

Comment: Where are you releasing the memory allocated in this statement: `block = new pixel*[blockHeight];` ?

Comment: @Deduplicator displayed is created from the image class -> image* currImage; (current image)
image* displayed; (for the new image, grabs the pixels and height/width when I need private data)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm really not sure how to fix this issue. I felt like I was creating the blocks wrong or not traversing the data into them correctly, I don't know how I can do it differently.

Comment: @leppie: Are you sure that's not C++? What language is it then?

Comment: @Deduplicator: `c++` + `VS` == `visual-c++`, but perhaps this generic enough for `c++`, but normally not.

Comment: @T-Bird Please post the `pixel` class.  You allocated memory for `block`, but then you use it on the right side of an equal sign, ex: `totred = totred + block[i][j].red;` implying it has valid values.  I don't see what these values are.

Comment: @nchen24 There isn't a "displayed" class, like I said it's created from an image class and my image* displayed is declared as a global variable to use to manipulate a copy of the current image.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Adding those parts right now.

Comment: @leppie I didn't know there was a visual-c++ tag specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well minus the massive memory leak and misleading name, you have the right idea in `CreateBlock` for finding the average.  I would try something along the lines of this:

```
pixel averagePixels(pixel **oldImage, int startRow, int startCol, int blockHeight, int blockWidth){
    float rTot, gTot, bTot;
    pixel avg;

    for(int i = startRow ; i < blockHeight + startRow ; i++){
        for(int j = startCol ; j < blockWidth + startCol ; j++){
            rTot += oldImage[i][j].red;
            gTot += oldImage[i][j].green;
            bTot += oldImage[i][j].blue;
        }
    }
    avg.red   = rTot / (blockHeight * blockWidth);
    avg.green = gTot / (blockHeight * blockWidth);
    avg.blue  = bTot / (blockHeight * blockWidth);
    return avg;
}

pixel **shrinkImage(pixel **oldImage, int blockHeight, int blockWidth){
    int newHeight = oldImage->getHeight() / blockHeight;
    int newWidth  = oldImage->getWidth()  / blockWidth;
    pixel **newImage = new pixel* [newHeight];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < newHeight ; i++)
        newImage[i] = new pixel[newWidth];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < newHeight){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < newWidth){
            newImage[i][j] = averagePixels(oldImage, blockHeight * i, blockWidth * j, blockWidth, blockHeight);
        }
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Disclaimer, I haven't actually tested any of this, and it would probably be wise (at least for testing purposes) to ensure that the new rgb values are within the acceptable range (0-255 I presume?).  You'll also need some bounds checking/special cases for when the image size is not perfectly divisible by the block size.

Comment: When it's not perfectly divisible, our teacher said it's just supposed to cut off that part and that's fine.  The RGB values are within the (0-255) range as well. I'll try this out though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `currpix` in your `CreateBlock` code. You are averaging random numbers allocated in the code:

```
block = new pixel*[blockHeight];
for (int i = 0; i < blockHeight; i++)
    block[i] = new pixel[blockWidth];
```

Comment: The code starts from the average regions function and then that one calls the other one.  I was creating the blocks there, but I guess I didn't set it correctly using the current pixels, and I'm not sure how to loop it and get all the pixels into each block.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are using uninitialized values here:

```
  totred = totred + block[i][j].red;
  totblue = totblue + block[i][j].blue;
  totgreen = totgreen + block[i][j].green;
```

You allocated `block`, but you failed to initialize any of the values.  Therefore `red`, `green` and `blue` have random values.

You also have a memory leak -- you allocated `block` here, but failed to deallocate it:

```
pixel** block; 
block = new pixel*[blockHeight];

for (int i = 0; i < blockHeight; i++)
    block[i] = new pixel[blockWidth];
```

Instead of this, the easiest solution is to use `std::vector<std::vector<pixel>>`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<std::vector<pixel> > block(blockHeight, std::vector<pixel>(blockWidth));
```

That one line of code does everything your loop accomplished, plus rids you of the memory leak.  The thing it really doesn't do is initialize `block` with the values you need to have.  What those values are -- you need to determine them.

Comment: It actually is totaling them correctly, it's just not applying it into each block. I stepped through the code and it does grab the pixel values while traversing them. I just can't get it to link to the blocks. I cannot use a vector either based on what pixel is, it has to be a pointer.

Comment: It seems to work correctly, but it is wrong.  You are creating a struct dynamically.  You are then using uninitialized data in the loop.  It doesn't matter what you observed, the code is wrong.  More than likely, you're running a debug build that sets values to 0.  Start to use a release build, and you will see those values more than likely have random garbage.

Comment: Hence why it comes to a gray image. How can I create the blocks correctly without using a vector format and setting them equal to the current pixels in the image?

Comment: I've been editing and working on this for awhile, moving things around, and I probably just forgot to delete it when I tried using it.